# Custom nameserver domain with CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system

We have quite a couple of domains where the rightful owner is us, but the nameserver is managed by a third party (subcontractor), who doesn't allow us to change the zone files.

Thus, we are moving to our new nameservers, which we can manage on our own, namely DigitalOcean's free DNS service.

Is it possible and if yes, what disadvantages would it bring if instead of requesting the nameserver change at the registrar for DO's nameservers, I would request a change for `ns1.example.com`, then I'd create a `CNAME` record that `ns1.example.com` points to `ns1.digitalocean.com`? Would that work?

In that case, if we ever have to move our DNS service from DigitalOcean to some other service, the registrar wouldn't need to change a hundred domains at once with all the administrative hassle, we could simply modify the abovementioned `CNAME` record.

Comment: Someone edited my question the wrong way. It's important that I wouldn't use `ns1.example.com` to resolve `example.com`, the NS for `example.com` would be independent and different, so as far as I understand I don't need a glue record. The question is however, should I use `CNAME` or `A` for my vanity nameserver and what drawbacks can I expect?

Comment: If you think you don't need a glue record, you haven't understood DNS properly.

Comment: Then please help clear my confusion here. Let's say user wants to visit `example2.com` and it has its NS record set to `ns1.example.com`. When querying `ns1.example.com`, to find out where it is, it must first find `example.com`. The authoritive nameserver for `example.com` however, is `ns1.digitalocean.com`, not  `ns1.example.com`. So there is no circular dependency. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your latest comment is correct, except that the way that you point out the authoritative nameserver is with a glue record, not just with a cname record. Otherwise, if the zone for example.com were to be unavailable, none of the domains using `ns.example.com` would be reachable.

Comment: `CNAME` records for namesevers are not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.
We have 7 domain and only one domain has glue records.
The disadvantage is you nameservers needs to do recursion queries and it is a bit if problem.
And btw you don't need to have CNAME record.
Just use the main glue records in SOA for other domains.
Also you can define ns records for other domains in your main domain (the one with glue records) and use define other one rather than the same as normal one.